# MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: The rowNum and colNum attribute was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.2

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, pycharm

I am using `matplotlib 3.2.0` and `panda 0.3.1` in `PyCharm 2019.2.6`
I have provided a static function for drawing as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class Drawing:
    @staticmethod
    def draw_hist(data_frame, bins='auto', figsize=(20, 15), color='#0504aa', alpha=0.7, rwidth=0.85):
        data_frame.hist(bins=bins, figsize=figsize, color=color, alpha=alpha, rwidth=rwidth)
        plt.show()
        plt.grid(axis='y', alpha=0.75)
        plt.xlabel('Value')
        plt.ylabel('Frequency')
        plt.title('My Very Own Histogram')
        plt.text(23, 45, r'$\mu=15, b=3$')
```

Although, this snippet draws the histogram but it causes some warning as follows:

> MatplotlibDeprecationWarning:  The rowNum attribute was deprecated in
>   Matplotlib 3.2 and will be removed two minor releases later. Use
>   ax.get_subplotspec().rowspan.start instead.   layout[ax.rowNum,
>   ax.colNum] = ax.get_visible()
>
> MatplotlibDeprecationWarning:  The colNum attribute was deprecated in
>   Matplotlib 3.2 and will be removed two minor releases later. Use
>   ax.get_subplotspec().colspan.start instead.   layout[ax.rowNum,
>   ax.colNum] = ax.get_visible()

Is there any way to correct this warning?

Comment: You can ignore or suppress the warning, or wait for pandas 1.0.2 (see [#32444](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/32444))

Comment: Already fixed in pandas 1.0.2.